# javascript: loop through cases

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

The function below checks the parent URL to see if the letters 'pid' exist in the query string of the parent URL. (it is in a cross domain iFrame). The function below works in an iFrame in Chrome, but not in Safari and IE.

In Safari and IE it seems to ignore 'document.referrer' and instead uses document.location, document.location.href, window.location, window.location.href, and document.documentURI to recognize if this exists in the query string of the parent URL.

I'd like to loop or cycle through each one of these looking into the URL to see if it includes a query string with the letters 'PID' in it. How is it best to check each one of these before going into my else or default ?

```
function colorchange() {
var match = /\?.*?pid/.test(document.referrer);

if (match) {
     console.log("pid pm");
  } else {
     console.log("standard pm");
  }
}

colorchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array of expected objects & loop through them to find the match.

Here's a pseudo code you can try.

```js
var pid_testers = [
  window.location.href,
  document.referrer,
  ..
];

var match = pid_testers.some(function (val) {
  if(... logic ..) {
    return val;
  }
});

// This will break when it finds a match..
```

Comment: can I then set another variable and if else statement like this:
`
var match = /\?.*?pid/.test(pid_testers);

 if (match) {  } else { }`

Comment: Yes mine is just a pseudo code to show one possibility, you can just loop through the possible cases and match. try to find the best way to write the logic inside the loop